# Get users of search products search results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I would know the best way to get all users who have products of the search result

My controller

```
    @users = User.all // i must change here ?
    if params[:product_type].present? && params[:location].present? && params[:discount].present?
      @products = Product.near(params[:location], 1, units: :km).where(product_type: params[:product_type], discount: params[:discount])
    end
```

My view

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.user.company_name %>
<% end %>
```

My method work but if a company have 2 products its display it 2 times

Comment: Might be as easy as calling _.uniq_ on _p.users.uniq.company_name_ but would need to see your models and associations to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following:

```
User has_many :products
Product belongs_to :user
```

You can do:

```
@users_from_product_results = User.where(id: @products.pluck(:user_id))
```

If several products refer to the same user, this User will be listed only once.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i get SQL error "subquery has too many columns"

Comment: @AntoineWako try my updated answer. Also, what DB system are you using?

Comment: I use PostgreSQL

Comment: @AntoineWako What is the Rails version you are using?

Comment: i use 5.1, now i dont get errors but i dont get users

Comment: @AntoineWako my bad... I took the problem the wrong way, see my updated answer

Comment: I get "ERROR:  column "distance" does not exist",  i dont know where it from

Comment: This is not related to the User model but most likely related to the Product. Can you post the full error message?

Comment: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "distance" does not exist
LINE 1: ... 0.0 AND 1) AND "biens"."product_type" = $1 ORDER BY distance A...
                                                             ^

Comment: Can you post the full SQL query instead? This seems to be related to the GeoCoder gem or whatever the GPS location gem you are using

Comment: SELECT "products"."user_id" FROM "products" WHERE (products.latitude BETWEEN 50.62025678394081 AND 50.63824321605919 AND products.longitude BETWEEN 3.043078628915486 AND 3.0714333710845145 AND (6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((50.62925 - products.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(50.62925 * PI() / 180) * COS(products.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((3.057256 - products.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1) AND "products"."product_type" = $1 ORDER BY distance ASC

Comment: Ok, I see ... The `near` method forces an order, can you try with `User.where(user_id: @products.reorder(:user_id).pluck(:user_id))`? -- What gem is providing you this `near` method? Geocoder?

Comment: It works ! Thanks for your help you save a french startup haha, its .where(id:....) not user_id

Comment: Ahah Im glad I helped you out. Have fun with rails!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making 2 separate AR calls, use includes(eager_loading) which gives both products and users in a single query.

```
if params[:product_type].present? && params[:location].present? && params[:discount].present?
  @products = Product.near(params[:location], 1, units: :km).where(product_type: params[:product_type], discount: params[:discount])
.includes(:user)
end
```

And in the view you could use `@products.map(:users).uniq` which gives all the users associated with the products.